# Finding one-to-one / one-to-many relationships between 2 columns

Tags: sql, oracle, relationship

I'm generating a list of part numbers and their family associated with it.  Some parts numbers belong to multiple families, where most are just associated with one.

To use round numbers, there are 600 distinct parts, where there are 750 distinct part/family relationships.  So what I'm trying to do is create a list of the part numbers that do not belong to just one family.

As an example, I've created a subset of data below that I'm looking at, and then also the expected return.

```
part_no       family
43d565rfd     ar94
43d000rfd     ur22
43d000rfd     e498
43d565r12     ur24
43d565rfd     ur24
43d365r56     ev69
43d365r56     as56
```

So essentially out of the above list, I'm only wanting to return:

```
part_no
43d000rfd
43d365r56
```

because they are part of multiple families.

Answer (score 3):

You can use aggregation and `having`:

```
select part_no
from t
group by part_no
having min(family) <> max(family);
```

Comment: Thanks ... this worked great.  `having` was exactly what I was missing

Answer (score 1):

Use the `HAVING` clause to filter out the parts that belong to a single family. For example:

```
select part_no
from (select distinct part_no, family from t) x
group by part_no
having count(*) > 1
```

Or:

```
select part_no
from t
group by part_no
having count(distinct family) > 1
```

Comment: Tested this out to see if it produced the same results as above, and it worked also.  Thank ya!

Answer (score 0):

If you want part no along with families linked to them and total count then you can use an analytical function as following:

```
SQL> WITH YOUR_TABLE(part_no, family) AS
  2  (SELECT '43d565rfd',     'ar94' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  3  SELECT '43d000rfd',     'ur22' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  4  SELECT '43d000rfd',     'e498' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  5  SELECT '43d565r12',     'ur24' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  6  SELECT '43d565rfd',     'ur24' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  7  SELECT '43d365r56',     'ev69' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  8  SELECT '43d365r56',     'as56' FROM DUAL)
  9  SELECT
 10      PART_NO,
 11      FAMILY,
 12      CNT   AS TOTAL_FAMILIES
 13  FROM
 14      (
 15          SELECT
 16              PART_NO,
 17              FAMILY,
 18              COUNT(1) OVER(
 19                  PARTITION BY PART_NO
 20              ) AS CNT
 21          FROM YOUR_TABLE
 22      ) WHERE CNT > 1
 23  ORDER BY PART_NO;

PART_NO   FAMI TOTAL_FAMILIES
--------- ---- --------------
43d000rfd ur22           2
43d000rfd e498           2
43d365r56 ev69           2
43d365r56 as56           2
43d565rfd ar94           2
43d565rfd ur24           2

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

or If you want families in the comma-separated list then use the following:

```
SQL>
SQL> WITH YOUR_TABLE(part_no, family) AS
  2  (SELECT '43d565rfd',     'ar94' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  3  SELECT '43d000rfd',     'ur22' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  4  SELECT '43d000rfd',     'e498' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  5  SELECT '43d565r12',     'ur24' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  6  SELECT '43d565rfd',     'ur24' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  7  SELECT '43d365r56',     'ev69' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  8  SELECT '43d365r56',     'as56' FROM DUAL)
  9  SELECT
 10      PART_NO,
 11      LISTAGG(FAMILY, ',') WITHIN GROUP(
 12          ORDER BY
 13              1
 14      ) AS FAMILIES,
 15      COUNT(1) AS TOTAL_FAMILIES
 16  FROM
 17      YOUR_TABLE
 18  GROUP BY
 19      PART_NO
 20  HAVING
 21      COUNT(DISTINCT FAMILY) > 1
 22  ORDER BY
 23      PART_NO
 24  ;

PART_NO   FAMILIES             TOTAL_FAMILIES
--------- -------------------- --------------
43d000rfd e498,ur22                         2
43d365r56 as56,ev69                         2
43d565rfd ar94,ur24                         2

SQL>
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Next on my list was figuring out a way to list out all the families associated with the parts that had more than one family, so I'll definitely be testing out the bottom portion of your suggestion.  Thanks!